# WPF Windows Get All Available Points

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Is there any clever way of getting all the available Points in a WPF Window? I already know how to get the Point of elements in the Window by using

```
.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Now I'm hoping there is a way to do this for an entire window. Hopefully something better than a brute force technique where I would have to use nested For Loops starting at point (0,0) and increasing by 1 in the Y and add it to a list until I run out, then increase X by 1 and check all the Y's again and repeat this process until I've run out of points.

If this is my best approach, what would be the best way to check if my next Point is actually on the window before trying to add it to the list. I feel like if I increase my either my X or Y value to a point that isn't on the Window it will throw some sort of out of range exception.

Comment: I think what you really want is the minimum and maximum. You probably don't need an enumeration of what could easily become a million points. You can use the `Width` and `Height` properties of a window to help determine this.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate my own version of Dijkstra's Algorithm. So I need all Points/Nodes in my Window so I can calculate the shortest path between two points. But if go For Loop approach, I can use width and Height property as my bounds so I don't try to add a Point not on the list. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: well, if you know you have a rectangular window, and you know the height and width you can easily create a double loop to create all the options. Is that different from what you're trying to do?